# Resource Owner grant type requiring client_id and client_secret in yii2-oauth2-server

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, yii2, authorization, yii-components

Why the password grant_type must be provided with client credentials (in this implementation)???. The oauth2 resource owner spec just needs

```
{
    "grant_type" : "password",
    "username" : "some_user_name",
    "password" : "some_password"
}
```

This implementation also requires the **client_id** and **client_secret** to be sent with this request to be successfull.

I just want to know if I'm missing something

Please refer also to http://andyfiedler.com/2014/09/how-secure-is-the-oauth2-resource-owner-password-credential-flow-for-single-page-apps

I want to grant access from my SPA to my protected resource. Exposing client credentials in the browser source code is potentially dangerous.

Also, the original library at https://bshaffer.github.io/oauth2-server-php-docs/overview/grant-types/ doesn't force client credential in resource owner grant type

**Update 1 13-12-2016**

Reading at the original library, I figured out that they have de concept of "public client" (that is, a client with no client_secret).

Using a public client, I can ommit the client_secret from the request. Anyway, I read again the resource owner spec, and no mention of that appears on it.

That way, a resource owner token request must be performed this way (non-standar)

```
{
    "grant_type" : "password",
    "username" : "some_user_name",
    "password" : "some_password"
    "cliend_id" : "some_client_id"
}
```

Bye

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For reference purposes the OAuth2 specification does cater for that scenario where a client without a secret can still pass the `client_id` parameter in the request body even though client authentication will not be completed. In section 2.3.1 you have:

> (...) the authorization server MAY support including the client credentials in the request-body using the following parameters:
>
> **client_id**
>   REQUIRED. The client identifier issued to the client during the registration process described by Section 2.2.
>
> **client_secret**
>   REQUIRED. The client secret. **The client MAY omit the parameter if the client secret is an empty string.**